# GORM: Serialize bytea to hex string

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have such table in psql:

```
TABLE transactions (
    hash bytea NOT NULL
)
```

And I want to get data from DB and return it as a response to user:

```
type Transaction struct {
    Hash []byte `gorm:"column:hash" json:"hash"`
}
```

```
func GetAllTransactions(c *gin.Context) {
    var transactions []models.Transaction
    initializers.Database.Limit(10).Find(&transactions)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"result": transactions})
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "hash": "LVeI8w7ugVs7s/AY3WUxnbR2s9a+P7b/1l1+6Z9K9jg="
        }
    ]
}
```

But by default `hash` has wrong data, I would like to get something like this:

```
SELECT '0x' || encode(hash::bytea, 'hex') AS hash_hex FROM transactions LIMIT 1;

0x2d5788f30eee815b3bb3f018dd65319db476b3d6be3fb6ffd65d7ee99f4af638
```

I tried to make `Scanner / Valuer`, but so far it hasn't helped

Comment: The JSON codec encodes `[]byte` values using base64.  Change the `hash` field to type `string` and set to the text you want in the JSON or declare a `[]byte` type that marshals to JSON as hex instead of base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an advice from [Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%C3%B3n), I made this one:

```
type HexBytes []byte

type Transaction struct {
    Hash              HexBytes `gorm:"column:hash" json:"hash"`
}

func (b HexBytes) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    hexStr := hex.EncodeToString(b)
    return []byte(`"0x` + hexStr + `"`), nil
}
```

And the response became like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "hash": "0x2d5788f30eee815b3bb3f018dd65319db476b3d6be3fb6ffd65d7ee99f4af638"
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe there is a better way, I'll be glad to see other suggestions